# angular digest already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know my exception is popular, but I read all the answers here but can't to seem to find solution.

I have ng-click that runs A c# code that open file-chooser.
in the other hand i have notification system in my web-app, that runs notification and removes it in 1.5 second.

Now the scenario for the exception that if i get notification in my app and in that 1.5 second i click on ng-click that launch file chooser,it will work but when the 1.5 seconds finish I will get exception '$digest already in progress'

I tried several solutions with $timeout but wasn't good to me:

-Setting $timeout flag in the notification popup to false, is not good because I need updated view after 1.5 seconds.

-Setting File-Chooser in $timeout also didn't work.

-Setting the whole method of File-Chooser in controller in $timeout also didn't work.

The best way is to check that after 1.5 seconds(when closing notification in $timeout), if there file-chooser, then not to close notification, or to use $timeout with flag false there, but in general to use $timeout with flag true when closing notification, but I failed to implement it.

Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Are you explicitly using $apply() or $digest()?

Comment: All what I use is $timeout in the notification system, and its set to 1.5 seconds, Because I need $timeout there.there no explicitly call to $digest() or $apply() in my code

Comment: try setting the $timeout interval to 0.

Comment: I would not suggest to use `$timeout`. Angular has a better solution for this called `$evalAsync`. The difference between the two is that what ever is wrapped inside `$timeout` is being executed once the call stack is empty. Additionally, it will wait for the current digest cycle to be done. `$evalAsync` on the other hand pushes the block onto something called  asyncQueue, which will likely be executed during the current or next digest cycle.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal setting $timeout to 0 in the notification system is not a solution, Because its 1.5 seconds as design, I want the notification to hide after 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @LordTribual is there an option inside $evalAsync to set delay to 1.5 seconds like $timeout?

Comment: No there is no option. If you really need the delay then you must use `$timeout`.

Comment: @LordTribual Then there no way to fix the problem?

Comment: It is really hard to tell from just your explanation. Can you recreate the issue in a Plunker? This helps people understand your problem.

Comment: @LordTribual I can't post code because my application is big, But is there a way to add condition inside $timeout to stop calling $apply in some cases?

Comment: The third parameter tells Angular whether to invoke an apply or not.